# L/K is Galois extension Prove that $Gal(L/N)=\cap_{\phi\in G} \phi H \phi^{-1}$

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose that $L/K$ is Galois extension with $G=Gal(L/K)$ and $M$ is immediate field of it. If $N\subseteq L$ is normal closure of $M/K$ and $H=Gal(L/M)$ then prove that $Gal(L/N)=\cap_{\phi\in G}{\phi H \phi^{-1}}$

I had solved that $Gal(L/N) \subseteq \cap_{\phi\in G}{\phi H \phi^{-1}}$ but the converse I can not. 
I take $\phi' \in Gal(L/N)$ then it is $K$ isomorphism and $\phi'(M)\subseteq N$ then $\cap_{\phi\in G}{\phi H \phi^{-1}} \subseteq \phi' H \phi'^{-1}$ and I do not know $\phi' \alpha \phi'^{-1}(n)=n$ with $\alpha \in Gal(L/M)$ is ok or not? Because $\phi'(M)\in N$ does not mean that $\phi'^{-1}(N)=M$

Comment: Should it be $H=Gal\left(N/K\right)$?

Comment: I doubt that @Guy. $Gal(N/K)$ is naturally a *quotient* group of $Gal(L/K)$.

Comment: So then should $H=G$?

Comment: I am sorry. That is my mistake

Comment: $H=Gal(L/M)$ sounds more natural.

Comment: use that $Gal(L/N)$ is the greatest ones subgroup of $ H$ that is
normal in $ G$.

Answer (score 3):

the field $N$  is the normalized of $M$ over $K$ in $L$, so it is
the smallest extension of $M$  such that $ Gal(L / N)$ is included
in $H = Gal (L / M)$ and normal in $Gal (L / K)$, so $Gal (L / N)$
is the greatest ones subgroup of $ H$ that is normal in $  G$.

so we reformulate this as a group theory problem:

he acted to show that if $H$ is a subgroup of  a group $G$ then
the largest subgroup $S$ of $H $  normal in $G$ is the
intersection of all conjugate of $H$ in $G$ , that is
$S=\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$.

Prove: yet clearly  this intersection is normal and include in $H$ that
is $\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}\subseteq S$ ,  $S$ is  normal in G and
$S$ include in $ H$,  then the conjugate of $S$ is included in all
conjugate of $H$ that is $S\subseteq\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$,  so
$S=\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: Can you explain more,please?

Comment: please, what you want to explain more?

Comment: Excellent answer using the regular action of a group on the left cosets of a subgroup and then taking the kernel of the induced homomorphism to be the core of the subgroup. Yet it could be the explanation is too frugal. For example, that "Clear this intersection is normal and contains $\;H\;$ ..." can be a long way for someone who hasn't worked out this. On the other hand, anyone studying Galois Theory must, I think, have taken already basic group theory...

Comment: Thank you, I got it. But I just do not know why G(N) is the greatest normal subgroup. I can see it is normal but I do not know the relation between closure and the greatest one.

Comment: withe pleasure:   Gal(L/N) is the greatest normal subgroup  in G and contain H , this equivalent to N is the smallest extension of M that is galoisienne over K  (galois théorie)

Comment: Thank you! You make me feel bad about myself :)

Comment: sorry, your question is very interesting, I voted positively for you, good luck!!